# How to query database by id using SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, model, sqlalchemy

I need to query a SQLAlchemy database by its `id` something similar to

```
User.query.filter_by(username='peter')
```

but for id. How do I do this? [Searching over Google and SO didn't help]

Comment: Please provide more details, like equivalent SQL or pseudocode doing what you want. What is "SQLAlchemy database id"?

Comment: Does your table have an id column?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Query has a [get function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.get) that supports querying by the primary key of the table, which I assume that `id` is.

For example, to query for an object with ID of 23:

```py
User.query.get(23)
```

---

Note: As a few other commenters and answers have mentioned, this is not simply shorthand for "Perform a query filtering on the primary key". Depending on the state of the SQLAlchemy session, running this code may query the database and return a new instance, or it may return an instance of an object queried earlier in your code without actually querying the database. If you have not already done so, consider reading the [documentation on the SQLAlchemy Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache) to understand the ramifications.

Comment: Get function also supports multiple primary keys: `YourModel.query.get((pk1, pk2))`. **Notice the tuple.**

Comment: The `get()` function queries objects by primary key. If you would like to query by `id`, you should set `id` as primary key first.

Comment: Since Query.get() is deprecated since 1.4 - is the replacement the `session.get(User, 5)` ?

Comment: @MarceloGazzola please ask a new question in a new thread, and if you need to comment on an old thread, please only comment on a single answer rather than 3 different ones. Thanks. That said, `User.query.filter(User.id.in_((23,24,25,58,21))).all()` should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time navigating and grokking the SQLAlchemy documentation.  Is the deprecated `Query.get()` method different than the `User.query.get(23)` method listed in this question? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.get
I want to avoid using a deprecated method, but I am have not been able to figure if I should use `User.query.get(23)` or not.  Thank you for your time 

Answer (score 67):

You can query a User with id = 1 like this

`session.query(User).get(1)`

Answer (score 11):

`get()` is not as your expected sometimes. If your transaction was done:

```
>>> session.query(User).get(1)
[SQL]: BEGIN (implicit)
[SQL]: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.name AS user_name, user.fullname AS user_fullname
FROM user
WHERE user.id = ?
[SQL]: (1,)
<User(u'ed', u'Ed Jones')>
```

If you are in a transaction, `get()` will give you the result object in memory without query the database:

```
>>> session.query(User).get(1)
<User(u'ed', u'Ed Jones')>
```

better to use this:

```
>>> session.query(User.name).filter(User.id == 1).first()
[SQL]: SELECT user.name AS user_name
FROM user
WHERE user.id = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
[SQL]: (1, 1, 0)
(u'Edwardo',)
```

Comment: How is this behavior unexpected?

Comment: I mean if you in a transaction (not session.commit yet) the `get()` seems to give you the result object in memory(without actually query the database), but the `filter().first()` will always query the database.

Comment: Is it possible to concurrently change the database during the transaction? If not, using `get` is better due to the increase in efficiency.

Comment: as I know the sqlalchemy cannot working with the async stuff( seems only with gevent ), and yes, the `get` is more efficient.

Comment: Why is .first() any different from .get() as far as the transaction is concerned?  Does .first() always go back to the database?  Is it that .get() looks in the current env first to see if it knows that id or something?

Comment: This is a good point but I don't think this is unexpected - this is exactly how *every* ORM with a cache works...it would be unexpected if it *didn't* do this

Comment: Yes, what I mean is we should aware `get()` use cache and `query().filter().first()` seems not.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `tables reflection` you might have problems with the solutions given.
(The previous solutions here didn't work for me).

What I ended up using was:

```
session.query(object.__class__).get(id)
```

(`object` was retrieved by reflection from the database, this is why you need to use `.__class__`)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As of SQLAlchemy 2.0, you can use:

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    user = session.get(User, 1)
    if user is not None:
        print(f'# user: {user.username}')
        print(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set `id` as the primary key.
Then you could use the `query.get()` method to query objects by `id` which is already the primary key.

Since the `query.get()` method to query objects by the primary key.
Inferred from [Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

def test():
    id = 1
    user = User.query.get(id)
```